Add legend in pyvis
I have python code to draw a graph with nodes ('A','B','C','D','E') but i am not able to add a legend:
I want a legend with the 3 colors, such as "lightblue" = descrpt1, "lightgreen" = descrpt2, "lightpink" = descrpt3.
I using pyvis.network to plot/save the html for later use.
I have seen some solutions with "plt.legend" but i think it is too complicated. Is there a way to do it with pyvis module itself?
Here is the code:
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.network import Network

node_kind1 = ['A','B']
node_kind2 = ['C','D']

graph = nx.DiGraph(G)

nt = Network('1200px', width="100%", directed=True, 
              filter_menu=True, cdn_resources='in_line')

for node in graph.nodes():
    if node in node_kind1:
        node_color = 'lightblue'
    else:
         if node in node_kind2:
             node_color = 'lightgreen'
         else:
             node_color = 'lightpink'
    nt.add_node(node, color=node_color)

nt.from_nx(graph, default_node_size=25)
nt.save_graph('graph.html')


You can add a separate node just for the legend.

@Adeva1, how? Could you have some ex.
